# Alternative to returning a 'nil' value in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have a function that looks up a user in a database by their email and returns a struct containing their ID, email, and hashed password. But since ColdFusion lacks a null/nil/none type, I can't figure out what to return if a user doesn't exist.

My first solution was to return `false`, then just use `if(user == false)` to see if a user exists, but with both `==` and `is`, ColdFusion will try to convert a valid user struct to a boolean and throw an error when it can't.

My second solution was to just `return;` without a value, but then my check becomes `if(isDefined("foo"))`. In my opinion, that looks quite ugly, and makes refactoring a bit trickier since the variable name is now also in a string...

Is there a clean way of returning a "nothing found" value in ColdFusion?

Comment: Don't know the language but you could throw a UserNotFound exception or return a struct with a user ID of -1.

Comment: I'd go with @SeanMcSomething, If you're expecting to get a user back then throwing an exception is pretty reasonable and allows you to structure your calling code nicely.

Comment: Another solution is to return an empty structure.

Comment: I'd rather not do this by throwing a [vexing exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CF has `isNull()` since CF9, e.g.:

```
<cffunction name="getUser">
  <cfargument name="userID">
  <cfquery name="qUser">
    SELECT * FROM users where userID = <cfqueryparam value="#userID#">
  </cfquery>
  <cfif qUser.recordCount>
    <cfreturn {name=qUser.name}>
  </cfif>
</cffunction>

<cfset var user = getUser(1)>
<cfif isNull(user)>
   <!-- user not found -->
<cfelse>
   Welcome #user.name#
</cfif>
```

Comment: Head's up: do Not define a return type.  Keep it as `any`.

Answer (score 1):

returning a blank `''` or `false` works fine.

the trick is in how the return is handled, because most likely you'll do an `if isStruct(result)` it doesn't matter what you return as long as it is not a structure